# how to reset window width and window scale onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, scale

im creating  a zoom effect using  jquery and javascript, (a code that was publised in net.magazine)
 but in my next step, trying  to adjust  this web to different devices( using media query .etc)
i face a problem 
im trying to detect window size (my laptop  screen size is . 1024 x 768)
and i get both window and  document  width/height  same result  =737x402 !?why?
is it because the scale onload is not fullscreen?

---

```
<div id=wrap>

<div id=container> 

<div id=content>

<div class=section id=first ></div>

<div class=section id=second ></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id=scroller ></div>
```

the css

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 

}
#wrap {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
#scroller {
height: 1500px;
}
#container {
 position: relative;
 top:-57px;
 margin:0 auto;
width: 1070px;
height: 665px;
}
#content {
height: 665px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
#front-first {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -o-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
background: url(images/pic1.jpg) no-repeat;
      background-size:70%;
position: absolute;
 z-index:20;
display: block;
width: 1070px;
height: 665px;
margin: 0 auto;
 }

 #front-second {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.3333);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.3333);
 -o-transform: scale(0.3333);
  transform: scale(0.3333);
    background: url(images/pic2.jpg) no-repeat;
      background-size:70%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index:20;
   display: block;
   width: 1070px;
   height: 665px;
  margin: 0 auto;
   }


   <script>


$(document).ready(function(){    
browserWindowheight = $(window).height();
alert(browserWindowheight);
browserWindowwidth = $(window).width();
alert(browserWindowwidth);


        function Zoomer(content) {
            this.content = content;
            this.scrolled = 0;
            this.levels = 4;
            this.docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            // bind Zoomer to scroll event
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this, false);
        }

        Zoomer.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
            if(this[event.type]) {
                this[event.type](event);
            }
        };
        Zoomer.prototype.scroll = function(event) {
            this.scrolled = window.scrollY / (this.docHeight - window.innerHeight );
        };
        Zoomer.prototype.scroll = function(event) {
            this.scrolled = window.scrollY / (this.docHeight - window.innerHeight );
            var scale = Math.pow(3, this.scrolled * this.levels), transformValue = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
            this.content.style.WebkitTransform = transformValue;
            this.content.style.MozTransform = transformValue;
            this.content.style.OTransform = transformValue;
            this.content.style.transform = transformValue;
        };
        function init() {
            var content = document.getElementById('content'),
            // init Zoomer constructor
            ZUI = new Zoomer(content);
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
                 }); 
             <script>
             </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer your question, but i google it and i found this: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

Hope it helps! =)

Comment: thanks:) but  i still get the same result 740X400 dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Use JS:

```
screen.width;
screen.height;
```

This will detect the *screen size and not the browser size

```
var winWidth = screen.width;
var winWidth = screen.height;
```

Comment: hi thanks, but again i get the same result -740 instead of 1204.